# printf is giving me the wrong output

Tags: java

I have

```
System.out.printf("$%.2f\t $%.2f\n ",c.getDifference(),c.getAccValue());
```

but c.getAccValue() always gives me the wrong output and I have no idea why. The formula for getDifference() is getAccValue() - principal, and that output is correct.

I used input 5000 8.25 5 quarterly

CD class:

```
package cd;

public class CD {
private int time; //in years, t
private double interest; //interest rate, r
private int principal; //principal, p
private String number;//number of times compounded, n

public CD(int time, double interest, int principal, String number){
this.time = time;
this.interest = interest;
this.principal = principal;
this.number = number;
}    

public int getTime(){
    return time;
}

public double getInterest(){
    return interest;
}

public int getPrincipal(){
    return principal;
}

public String getNumber(){
    return number;
}

public double getAccValue(){
    double A = 0;
    interest = interest/100;
         if( "daily".equals(number)) {
                A = Math.pow(1 + interest/365, 365*time) * principal;
         }
         else if ("weekly".equals(number)){
                A = Math.pow(1 + interest/52, 52*time) * principal;
         }
         else if ("monthly".equals(number)){
                A = Math.pow(1 + interest/12, 12*time) * principal;
         }
         else if ("quarterly".equals(number)){
                A = Math.pow(1 + interest/3, 3*time) * principal;
         }
         else if ("semiannually".equals(number)){
                A = Math.pow(1 + interest/2, 2*time) * principal;
         }
         else if ("annually".equals(number)){
                A = Math.pow(1 + interest/1, 1*time) * principal;
         } 
        return A;
    }

public double getDifference(){
    return getAccValue() - principal;
 }
}
```

CDTest class:

```
package cd;

import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class CDTest {

 /**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here


    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Principal value, "
            + "Interest rate, time (in years), " + " and number of months"
            + " compunded" + "\n(Separated by spaces)");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(input);
    int principal = in.nextInt();
    double interest = in.nextDouble();
    int time = in.nextInt();
    String number = in.next();

    CD c = new CD(time, interest, principal, number);

    System.out.println("Principal   " + "Interest   " + "Maturity   " + 
            "Number Compounded   " + "Amount Gained   " + 
            "Accumulated Value   " + "");
    System.out.println("=========   " + "========   " + "========   " 
            + "=================   " + "=============   " + 
            "=================   ");
    System.out.printf("  $" + c.getPrincipal() + "\t      "); 
    System.out.print(c.getInterest() + "%" + "\t  "); 
    System.out.print(c.getTime() + "\t      ");
    System.out.print(c.getNumber() +" \t");
    System.out.printf("$%.2f\t $%.2f\n ",c.getDifference(),c.getAccValue());          
    }  
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Edit:

Current output is:

```
Principal   Interest   Maturity   Number Compounded   Amount Gained     
=========   ========   ========   =================   =============  
  $5000       8.25%       5         quarterly           $2510.99    
Accumulated Value 
=================   
$5020.66
```

Expected output is:

```
Principal   Interest   Maturity   Number Compounded   Amount Gained     
=========   ========   ========   =================   =============  
  $5000       8.25%       5         quarterly           $2510.99    
Accumulated Value 
=================   
$7510.99
```

Comment: Whats the output and what is the expected output?

Comment: output should be Difference = $2510.99 and AccValue = $7510.99

Comment: So that is the *expected* output? What is the *actual* output? Or do you expect everyone reading this question to run your code to see? And don't tell us actual output in a comment. Edit the question and clarify it, by showing both *actual* and *expected* outputs.

Comment: Sorry about that :/

Comment: Why is your question title blaiming `printf`? There is nothing wrong with `printf` or the format string you gave it. It prints exactly the number you gave it.

Comment: Add `final` to all your fields, and you'll see why you get wrong output. *Hint:* Value of `interest` is modified by a `get` method, which is a big no-no.

Comment: Then what might be the cause of the incorrect output? The difference is AccValue - principal, and it comes out with the correct output, but when I just want to print the AccValue, the output is incorrect and I'm confused as to why that happens

Answer (score 0):

```
     else if ("quarterly".equals(number)){
            A = Math.pow(1 + interest/3, 3*time) * principal;
```

You're multiplying by 3.  But there are 4 quarters in a year.  So, I would double check this formula.

Also, you have this line:

```
interest = interest/100;
```

in `getAccValue`.  This permanently changes the interest rate.  But, `getAccValue` is called by `getDifference`.  So when the difference is calculated, it divides the interest rate by 100 - and then when `getAccValue` is called by itself, it divides the interest rate by 100 *again*.  So now your interest rate is tiny and it's showing hardly any money made at all.

Comment: Wow I'm an idiot. I was thinking 3 months = 1 quarter when I wrote the formula. This actually fixed my problem, thanks a bunch

Comment: While this is *also* true, that is not actually the problem OP is asking about. OP is asking why output values don't add up, i.e. why `Accumulated Value` is not equal to `Principal + Amount Gained`. Reason for that is the [corruption of the `interest` value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43480163/printf-is-giving-me-the-wrong-output#comment74016428_43480163) inside the `getAccValue()`, which is executed *twice*.

Comment: Oh wow, that makes sense. I changed the interest formula in getInterest() and used it instead, thanks!

Comment: Hah, you commented while I was editing to add that part.